# How can I use SkiaSharp a suitable tool to draw a simple bar chart

Tags: xamarin, skiasharp

I'm using Xamarin Forms and I would like to add a very simple bar chart. What are the advantages and disadvantages of using SkiaSharp for this?

Note that the chart would be a simple xy chart with 10 points on the X axis and 1 - 500 on the Y axis.

Comment: https://components.xamarin.com/view/barchart If you are using Forms you can read that https://blog.xamarin.com/visualize-your-data-with-charts-graphs-and-xamarin-forms/

Comment: I noticed some people commenting that the barchart component does not work well. Have you used that yourself?

Comment: No, I am using HighCharts. Amazing control, not free but worth every dollar